# In IE 7-9 containers starts to overlap/shrink after 2nd block

Tags: image, internet-explorer, css-float

First, the images disapeared, I fixed by placing `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` in header, that's nice!

Now the images are showing but overlaping after the 2nd block [[IMG]](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/1146/clipboard02o.png). Im'finding hard to solve this because can't install IE 7-9, I rely on emulators such netrenderer :(

Header is `<!DOCTYPE html>` tried some other but anything change.

Containers goes like this:

```
<div class="post-container-odd" >
<h2><a href="http://site.com/destinos/africa-ilhas/">África &amp; Ilhas</a></h2>
<div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://site.com/destinos/africa-ilhas"  title="Ilhas Maldivas"><img src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/maldivas-22-380x200.jpg" title="" alt=""/></a></div>
</div>

<div class="post-container-even" >
<h2><a href="http://site.com/destinos/america-do-norte-caribe/">América do Norte &amp; Caribe</a></h2>
<div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://site.com/destinos/america-do-norte-caribe"  title="Chicago"><img src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/chicago-29-380x200.jpg" title="" alt=""/></a></div>
</div>
```

And CSS is just this:

```
.post-container-even{float:left;margin:0 0 20px 0;display:table}
.post-container-odd {float:left; margin: 0 5px 20px 0}
```

Added a `ie.css` with this (solved some issues but still overlapping):

```
.post-container-odd { float:left; margin: 0 5px 30px 0; display:inline;}

.post-container-even{ float:left; margin:0 0 30px 0; display:inline; clear: left}

.post-container-even img, .post-container-odd img { height: 200px ; width: 380px ; display:block; clear: both}

.post-container-even .thumbnail, .post-container-odd .thumbnail { height: 200px ; width: 380px ;  }
```

Maybe place a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` every two iten can solve but that is quite lame?

Thanks for any help

**Note:**

Without the `ie.css` instructions: [Image](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/8104/withoutq.png)

Now, with `ie.css`: [Image](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/1146/clipboard02o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I solved by placing:

```
zoom: 1; *display:inline; in image containers.
```